# TabBarController does not autorotate

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, uitabbarcontroller, autorotate

From my modal view controller, you can choose between two options, then each one shows a tabBar and so on. My Modal view clearly auto rotates, but the tabBars do not, even though I set for every UIViewController in my Project:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
// Return YES for supported orientations
return YES;
}
```

I even had a new view with tabBar that was supposed to be called when in Landscape mode, but unfortunately it is still in Potrait:

[image: Looks weird to me:]

Looks weird to me.

Comment: You don't have 'iPad' in the left top corner - have you jailbroken your device? In that case, are you using anything that could cause strange behavior like this? The only times I've seen this was on beta devices...

Comment: It does look weird as the UITabBar seems to rotate but the status bar does not (or the other way around). Your entire viewController stack may have issues as this is clearly an uncommon result.

Comment: No, not Jailbreaked at all :) Just the standard one, connected via USB …

Comment: Another weird thing is that when i configure the plist file of my target and set the interface orientation to portrait, my "Intro"view with the selection is still able to autorotate…

Answer (score 2):

In iOS, the view will only rotate if all views agree.

Make sure that your `UITabBarController` also agrees, and the other tabs as well.

Comment: +1 for correct answer - also make sure that in case you are using a UINavigationController in your app, all views on its/their stack agree on the rotation.

Comment: I did, as mentioned above, every viewController returns `YES`.